# Calculate expression out of the class

Tags: ruby

I am trying to send an expression to a class and get the result. I don't know in advance what the expression would be and I get it as a string form the user. and I can't run it from in the class

```
class MyClass

  def self.alias1
    return 1
  end
  def self.alias2
    return 2
  end

  # I can't do that:
  #@result =  alias1+alias2
  #print @result.to_s

end # end class MyClass

# That is working
inst1 = MyClass.new
result = inst1.send("alias1")
# result = 1

# I want to do that:
inst = MyClass.new
result = inst.send("alias1+alias2")
print result
```

expected result:

```
3
```

now I am getting an error that the method "alias1+alias2" doesn't exist.
From Ruby:
main: undefined method `alias1+alias2' for MyClass:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: Your first example `inst1.send("alias1")` should result in a `NoMethodError: undefined method `alias1'` because `alias1` is a class method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's clean up your class:

```
class MyClass

  def one
    1
  end

  def two
    2
  end

end
```

You can use [`instance_eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) to evaluate arbitrary expression in the context of your `MyClass` instance:

```
m = MyClass.new
m.instance_eval("one + two")
#=> 3
```

But this is dangerous. The user could define additional methods, access the filesystem or run shell commands.

Therefore, you should parse and evaluate the expression yourself.

Comment: Even better is to use the block version.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I understand the danger and I will take it under consideration. Thanks for the answer.